# Gitlab push very slow - Gitlab-CE

Tags: git, gitlab

Gitlab push is very slow, Is there any settings I can modify on the internal gitlab-ce server that can make the git push much faster? Right now the `push` speed is `13.00 KiB/s`.

I have some large repo still hasn't committed to gitlab due to its speed.

setting `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` gets stuck at `POST git-receive-pack (37437584 bytes)` for very long time.

setting `git config http.postBuffer 5242` starts pushing but at very low speed.

```
`Writing objects:  76% (73/95), 3.72 MiB | 13.00 KiB/s`
```

I read that `git config http.postBuffer` doesn't make it faster since only the local buffer is faster but the push still depends on the server accepting speed. So wondered if anything can be tuned on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling `IPv6` and rebooting the gitlab server seems to have fixed the issue.

One more reason it could be slow is if you're using `IPTABLES` and don't have a accept rule for `loopback interface` like this `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`.